# Auto comment java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, comments

Is there a code or plugin for netbeans to auto generate comments for functions and variables 
Not just to put

```
/** 
*@param name
*@return 
*/
```

I want to add method name info eg. If my function name follow java name convention   " Player getPlayerName (boolean isNewPlayer )" so the comment of the function will be

```
/** 
* get player name
* @param boolean is new player
* @return player
*/
```

I searched alot but I didn't find one put function description it just put tags of parameter